# CiviMobile Only Shows Events

Tags: drupal, civimobile

I set up a test domain to try CiviMobile. I got it to work but it only shows the test event I set up. Drupal 9.1.9 / CiviCRM 5.37.2 / CiviMobileAPI 5.6.1 / PHP 7.4.14 / Android 8.0.0

I have administrative rights. When I logout of CiviMobile it presents the login screen.  When I login it spins a bit then stays on the login screen, showing my username and password and above it, it says You are connected to https://xxx.dreamhosters.com. If I mess up the password it gives me an error message. I touch "Back" on the login screen and it says 'There are no events'. If I touch <-- Back at the top of the screen, I get the 'Change server' message. If I say OK, it shows the Civi URL and a Connect button. Touch that and it shows the test event I set up, but there's no other menu items along the bottom of the screen. I can't see any of the contacts in the database. I installed the CiviCalendar Extension too, but it doesn't show up. The CiviMobile Checklist looks good, except it says the **Rest url and the Rest Path are not correct. What's that?**  Please advise...thanks!

**UPDATE**:
I found rest.php, but it was in .../ffv.dreamhosters.com/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/extern. Then I realized Civi Directories & Resource URLs had different [civicrm.root] directories, so I posted [Resource URLs Screen has the wrong [civicrm.root]](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/39742/resource-urls-screen-has-the-wrong-civicrm-root) Then I moved my Extensions directory to the preferred location: .../sites/default/files/civicrm/ Reinstalled CiviMobile, Updated Paths, emptied the Civi cache and my browser cache.  But it's still complaining that the Rest Path is wrong, so I copied the Extern directory to where CiviMobile wants it to be .../libraries/civicrm/core/ but it's still not happy...Please Help!

Comment: Hi did you figure this out? I'm having the same problem with a fresh install of Drupal 9.

Comment: We're not using CiviMobile at this time.  If you read the comments below, you'll see I got it to work with WordPress which was our preferred CMS anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem with a fresh install of Drupal 9.

I've managed to get rid of the "REST url path incorrect" message at /civicrm/civimobile/checklist in a very hacky way, but still when I use the app on my phone the only thing that is visible is Events.

Here is how I got REST working:

1. Added "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/libraries/civicrm/core/extern/rest.php$" to .htaccess in web root (note this gets overwritten when you use "composer require").
2. created web/libraries/civicrm/core/civicrm.config.php file by copying it from an older installation, as this file is missing in a fresh D9 + Civi install.
3. copied the directory vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/extern to web/libraries/civicrm/core.
4. Edited civicrm.config.php and added the following at line 86:  $confdir = '../../../sites/default';

Comment: This solution almost worked for us. Had to make a few changes as per https://civihosting.com/blog/civimobile-and-drupal-9/

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure **permission settings** are correct:
https://civimobile.org/permissions/
In order to **view the calendar**, they should be
CiviCRM: access CiviCRM backend and API
CiviCRM: view my contact
CiviEvent: access CiviEvent
CiviEvent: view event info

**View contacts:**
CiviCRM: access CiviCRM backend and API
CiviCRM: view my contact
CiviCRM: view all contacts

---

Please also check the calendar settings in **Administration/CiviMobile/CiviMobile Calendar Settings**:
[image]

Did you check "Synchronize with CiviCalendar"?
[image]

---

Did you **clear the cache** afterwards?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply! The calendar was synched.  I just cleared the cache on my browser and reconnected with CiviMobile, but no change.  I'm the administrator that recently set up this test domain.  The Drupal, Civi everything.  I can see and edit my contacts and Events in CiviCRM. When I look at the Drupal > People > Permissions they all have a greyed out check mark under Administrator, except a few of the more basic permissions where Anonymous and Authenticated users are checked.  I can't find rest.php anywhere (see the end of my original question).  Is that a problem?

Comment: Yes, it is! Did you upgrade from an older drupal version? Have a look at https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3153769#comment-13948137 I don't run CiviCRM/CiviMobile on Drupal, therefore I'm not sure, if this corresponds to the wrong feature behaviour in your case...

Comment: It's a fresh install of everything. I didn't upgrade Drupal. Thanks for the link, but it doesn't say how to find the file that needs editing.

Comment: rest.php should be in /drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/extern/rest.php Probably the path to the civicrm.settings.php file is not correct and as consequence the APIv3 Rest query doesn't work?!

Comment: I'm still stuck and frustrated. Please see Update to my original post.  Thanks in advance...

Comment: I got CiviMobile to work reasonably well on a WordPress website.  Is anyone using 5.6.1 CiviMobile with Drupal 9?